# Where is the solution uniquely determined by the data?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations, cauchy-problem

**Question:**

Solve the PDE

$$y\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x^2} + (y-x)\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x \partial y} -x \frac{\partial u^2}{\partial y^2} = \frac{y-x}{y+x}\bigg(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\bigg) \qquad \text{for } x+y \neq 0$$

with initial data

$$u(x,1)=x \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,1) = -1 \qquad \qquad \text{for } x\geq 0$$

State where your solution is uniquely determined by this initial data.

---

**Attempt:**

So the two sets of characteristics are

$$x^2+y^2 = \text{constant} \qquad \text{and} \qquad x-y = \text{constant}$$

Using the change of variables $\xi = x^2+y^2$ and $\eta = x-y$, the equation reduces to

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \xi \partial \eta} = 0$$

Integrating, changing back to $x,y$ variables, and using the initial data, we find the solution

$$u(x,y) = x-y+1$$

**However, where is this solution uniquely determined by the initial data?** To determine this, do you simply plot the set of characteristics that touch the data curve then take the region crossed by both sets of characteristics?

I think there was also something about the Jacobian having to be non-zero?

So in this case, the data curve is $y=1$ for $x \geq 0$. The characteristics that touch this line are given by

\begin{align}
x^2+y^2 = c \qquad & c \geq 1 \\
x-y = d \qquad & d \geq -1
\end{align}

Does this mean that the solution is uniquely determined in the region

$$\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: x^2+y^2 \geq 1 \text{ and } x-y \geq -1 \}$$

shown in yellow below:

[image]

**And also, what happens on the line $x+y=0$?**